# Where is the error in this limits?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Find (if exists): $$\lim_{x^2+y^2\to +\infty,\; (x,y)\ \in \ R} \frac{xy^2}{1+x^2+x^2y^2}$$
where $R=[1,+\infty[\times[1,+\infty[$

---

My attempt:
$f(0,t)\equiv0$; so if the exists it must be ZERO.
I noticed(?) $f(2,t), t\ge1$ is $\left(\frac{2t^2}{1+4+4t^2}\right)$ whose limit for $t\to+\infty$ is $\frac{1}{2}$.
So, I supposed the limit could not exist. Anyway I know it's false and the limit exists.

---

Comment: $(0, t) \notin R$.

Comment: @MartinR Nooo... the biggest oversight of my life!! So, I must find an estimation like:  $\frac{1}{2} \le f(x,y) \le \frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Well, the limit does not exist! Consider $f(1, y)$ and $f(2, y)$ for $y \to \infty$.

Comment: @Martin, I still think the lit doesn't exist. If you substitute $x=r\cos \theta, y= r\sin\theta$, then the limit depends on $\theta$, which means it's directionally dependant on how you go outward from the origin

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan: I agree (see my previous comment). But the given reasoning is wrong.

Comment: Try changing coordinates of $x$ and $y$ such that $(1,1)$ become $(0,0)$. Then try calling $x:=\rho\cos(\theta)$ and $y:=\rho\sin(\theta)$, rewrite $R$ and then you should find the result comparing the power of $\rho$ in the fraction

Comment: How is it wrong? If the limit isn't the same for any direction I approach, then it doesn't exist, right?

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan - substituting $x = r\cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$ gives you a rational function in $r$ with degree $3$ numerator and degree $4$ denominator. Regardless of $\theta$ that will go to $0$ as $r^2 \to \infty$, so your claim of dependence on $\theta$ is false. To get a different limit, you need to follow paths where $\theta$ changes with $r$.

Comment: @DOmonoXYLEDyL - If your book or teacher claims this converges, probably they are interpreting the limit differently than Martin R. I agree wholly that Martin R's interpretation is justified, but perhaps the author meant for $r \to \infty$ without changing the angle $\theta$, as Dhanvi Sreenivasan was calculating, but chose a really poor way of expressing that.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the long absence..

Comment: @MartinR if you write your comment as an answer, I will accept it